# Installing Read/Write locks documentation on Debian

Tags: debian, man, documentation, pthreads

I'm trying to write a program that uses read/write locks and would like to install the man pages for this type of lock.

I already have installed the packages

- manpages-dev
- man-db
- glibc-doc

Could you please tell me the package that installs them or at least how to locate it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux (two kinds of) locks are implemented in [`flock(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/flock.2) and in [`fcntl(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/fcntl.2).

As you already have installed *manpages-dev* both are available with `man 2 flock` and `man 2 fcntl`.

In case you are talking about POSIX threads locking (per the tag), POSIX additional manpages are available in [*manpages-posix-dev*](https://packages.debian.org/buster/manpages-posix-dev), in the *non-free* packages section, and thus appear to not be available through usual online Debian manpages links. From the [package contents](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/manpages-posix-dev/filelist), this should be what you're looking for once installed:

```
pthread_rwlock_destroy.3posix
pthread_rwlock_rdlock.3posix
pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock.3posix
pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock.3posix
pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock.3posix
pthread_rwlock_trywrlock.3posix
pthread_rwlock_unlock.3posix
pthread_rwlock_wrlock.3posix
pthread_rwlockattr_destroy.3posix
pthread_rwlockattr_getpshared.3posix
pthread_rwlockattr_init.3posix
pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared.3posix
```

Comment: Thanks. In the package website it says to change /etc/apt/sources.list to get the packages from non-free and then I was able to install the manpages smoothly. It's just weird that these manpages are in the non-free.

Comment: The prolog to these manpages says to consult the corresponding Linux manpages, or they are not implemented in Linux. What are the Linux manpages or aren't these implemented in Linux?

Comment: It's a standard disclaimer boilerplate. On my Debian 10 system I have this in place for example `grep pthread_rwlock_rdlock /usr/include/pthreads.h` =>   `extern int pthread_rwlock_rdlock (pthread_rwlock_t *__rwlock)`. Also `readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 |grep pthread_rwlock_rdlock`'s output probably tells it exists "only" since glibc 2.2.5 released in 2002.

Comment: really. manpages such as `pthread_cancel` are available both in section 3posix and section 3, but other are not simply because they were never "translated", not because the feature doesn't exist. Beside I addressed your question as it was written